# UIImageView is displaying not correct

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I've placed UIImageView in my custom cell (Swift 3):

```
let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Feedcell", for: indexPath) as! FruitTableViewCell

let hero: List_Feed
        hero = heroes[indexPath.row]

if(hero.photo==""){
            cell.cnHeight.constant = 0
            cell.cnTopMargin.constant = 0
            cell.cnBottomMargin.constant = 52
            cell.imgPhoto.image = UIImage()
            cell.imgPhoto.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
        }else{
            cell.cnTopMargin.constant = 14
            cell.cnBottomMargin.constant = 50
            cell.imgPhoto.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
            //displaying image
            Alamofire.request(hero.photo!).responseImage { response in
                debugPrint(response)
                if let image = response.result.value {
                    //let newWidth = containerView.frame.height * ratio
                    let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
                    let width = bounds.size.width
                    let imagewidth = image.size.width
                    let imageheight = image.size.height
                    let ot1 = width / imagewidth
                    let ot2 = round(ot1 * imageheight)
                    //let ot3 = round(ot2 / 2)
                    //let ot4 = ot3 - 12
                    //let ot5 = ot4 + 50
                    cell.cnHeight.constant = ot2
                    cell.imgPhoto.image = image
                }
            }
        }
```

That's how it should be displayed: 
[image]

And it's how it displays when I scroll down and then scroll up:

[image]
(suddenly uiimageview covers all custom cell space)

Comment: You are using autolaout , Then why `cell.imgPhoto.frame`

Comment: After constant changes are you doing layoutIfNeeded() ?

Comment: Why you are downloading image again and again when cell shows ? .You should use SDWebImage library or  alamofire image library to cache image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // all your ui code
}
```

You are probably still on a background thread.

Comment: Where I should insert this method? After class: ClassName? or after viewDidLoad?

Comment: In the response. All that code needs to be inside this in the response.

Comment: It's still showing image and cell randomly, sometimes it's right, but sometimes image covers entire cell

Comment: And also image becomes white on scroll

Comment: On mobile so I am limited. I would say setting the frame to 0 before each call is probably not best. How are you giving the tableview the height of the cell

Comment: I'm giving 0 because not all cells should have a visible image. I give height of cells by autolayout